# Laravel 8.X validation on attributes that contain a certain string

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to make an application that saves grocery lists and retrieves them from a database.  In the request, the values get passed along in JSON format:

```json
"item:47" => "{"id":47,"name":"Beer","brand":"Jupiler","weight":null,"note":"Six pack;_bottles","order_id":15}"
"item:88" => "{"id":88,"name":"Tomatoes","brand":null,"weight":null,"note":null,"order_id":15}"
"item:110" => "{"id":110,"name":"Gura_Bread","brand":null,"weight":0.3,"note":null,"order_id":15}"
"item:-1" => "{"id":-1,"name":"Beef_Jerky","brand":"Canadon","weight":0.5,"notes":"Spicy_Ones"}"
```

*New items are marked with a descending negative id, while existing items retain their id from the DB*

When this arrives in the back-end of the laravel application, I would like to validate the JSON string with Laravel's `validate()`. The only problem is that the amount of items that can be passed varies in amount. Sometimes it can be one item, while other times it could be 10 items instead.

Is there a way to add this JSON rule that could only trigger when it notices that there's a certain string in one or multiple attributes of an incoming request? In this case, it should trigger when it sees that the string `item:`.

For context, here are the parameters of an example request.

```
"picking_method" => "Cheapest"
"item:47" => "{"id":47,"name":"Beer","brand":"Jupiler","weight":null,"note":"Six pack;_bottles","order_id":15}"
"item:88" => "{"id":88,"name":"Tomatoes","brand":null,"weight":null,"note":null,"order_id":15}"
"item:110" => "{"id":110,"name":"Gura_Bread","brand":null,"weight":0.3,"note":null,"order_id":15}"
"item:-1" => "{"id":-1,"name":"Beef_Jerky","brand":"Canadon","weight":0.5,"notes":"Spicy_Ones"}"
"store_street" => "Haag Pines"
"store_number" => "1855"
"store_postal_code" => "82792-01"
"store_city" => "Port Muhammadhaven"
"store_country" => "Guernsey"
"delivery_street" => "Rosenbaum Island" 
"delivery_number" => "4974"
"delivery_postal_code" => "61093"
"delivery_city" => "East Carlee"
"delivery_country" => "Slovenia"
"delivery_notes" => null
"medical_notes" => null
```

Comment: Take a lokk here in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules
You can make your custom validation rule it is very easy.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to re-use the `JSON` rule that Laravel offers. 
From what I understand out of the docs, you can use a custom rule to make a completely new rule with new logic, but I just want that the `JSON` rule gets used on certain attributes that start with `item:`

Comment: Maybe change your JSON structure to a single value, then the JSON validation will check the entire object as valid JSON and you can break it up later.

Comment: You can in the rule do what you want. explode the keys in a loop and check for item. If you explain a little bit more your answer with examples i can write you here a solution.

Comment: @MikeAron After I've posted this, I also came up with that possibility while working on something else and the method works. I'll update the post with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After experimenting some more, I came up with this solution.*

In order for this method to work, you'll need to have a substring that is the same across all the attributes that you want to check.

Before performing any validation at all, I decided to collect all the attributes that I want to check into an array with a `foreach` loop. This is where the substring part is important because it will be used to decide which attributes will be collected:

```php
$item_attributes = [];
    foreach ($request->post() as $key => $value) {
        if (str_contains($key, 'item:')) {
            array_push($item_attributes, $key);
        }
    }
```

After that, I looped over the `$item_attributes` array and used it to make a rules array, where every value in the `$item_attributes` is used as a key. As value, I added the `json` rule.

```php
$rules = [];
    foreach ($item_attributes as $attribute) {
        $rules[$attribute] = "json";
    }
```

After that, I validate the data and returned it, so it can be used in the main function of my code:

```php
return $request->validate($rules);
```

When combined, this will result into the following method:

```php
function validateItems(Request $request)
{
    $item_attributes = [];
    foreach ($request->post() as $key => $value) {
        if (str_contains($key, 'item:')) {
            array_push($item_attributes, $key);
        }
    }
    $rules = [];
    foreach ($item_attributes as $attribute) {
        $rules[$attribute] = "json";
    }
    return $request->validate($rules);
}
```